# how to do this scenario in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have the following table in which the status column value will be updated dynamically when an informatica workflow is executed.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[logging](
[id] [int] NULL,
[workflow] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[status] [int] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
insert into dbo.logging values(2,'wf_d','5')
insert into dbo.logging values(3,'wf_d','6')
insert into dbo.logging values(4,'wf_d','4')
```

I need to display all rows from some table say example products when value for the Status column turns to 3 for an particular row(in this example id=4). How to do this in oracle SQL.
I got some dirty solution for this problem in SQL server

```
DECLARE @compareprice int
label:
set @compareprice = (select status from logging where id=4)
if (@compareprice = 3)
select * from dbo.products;
else
goto label;
```

At some point when this code is executed the status code for id=4 in the table logging will turn to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you running this at in SQL server?? I can't imagine your DBA would be very happy about this since you are executing a query over and over and over again in a loop until something changes...

You can sort of do this with a PL/SQL block, but you really shouldn't though, since you are executing hundreds of select statements per second without a sleep somewhere.

You can use a trigger in both oracle and SQL server to have something execute when a row changes.

For example, you could run a SQL agent job in SQL server:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b672ee45-7198-4783-8143-2908f8a954d2/how-to-execute-sql-server-agent-job-from-trigger

Or a dbms_job in oracle:
[Can a JOB be created dynamically inside a trigger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375946/can-a-job-be-created-dynamically-inside-a-trigger)

Really, you ought to just set up a task that depends on the informatica job. Failing that, poll the table every 30 seconds with a little external C# or app (or something) that does what you want...

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. My oracle service doesnt startup for some reason on my home PC thats why tried this on SQL Server. I said the same thing to my client that DBA will literally kill me if i want to achieve this task but still they want me to give it a try. I have got no access for VS so i cant try polling the table.How will be the performance if i do it with trigger. Can u provide me some example of how to do this with trigger. the above query would run max for 5 minutes.

Comment: What does the client want? A CSV file export? Where is the query going to save its results? If you go the trigger route, as long as the dbo.logging table isn't being updated hundreds of times, a PL/SQL trigger on the dbo.logging table that checks for the appropriate "new" value shoudn't be bad for performance.

Comment: yes. they want a CSV file export. Im running all the SQL script from an Shell Script. I tried triggering option and it doesnt seems to be an viable solution. the logging table updates so many times. Is there any other options left for me?

Comment: If all you need is a CSV export, why not just run a Informatica task to select the data and dump to a file after Informatica runs the job that updates it. Is there any way you can tie into that informatica job and run a shell script after it finishes? Modified the KSH, etc??

Comment: No that is not possible. the client using informatica in a very different way so can get information using pmcmd directly. so im left now with no choices. is there any left

Comment: You could write a Unix script that polls the database table every 30 seconds via a cron job or other scheduled task. You could write a powershell script to do the same on windows. There's lots of options to poll the table, just because a trigger won't work doesn't mean that there are "no choices".

Comment: Thanks now i got some hope on this. i have not found good info about polling table from unix script. do u have syntax or any info how to do that. thanks

Comment: I have got some similar example in Unix forum. I will try this out tomorrow in office and let u know. thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

```
X=$(sqlplus -s user/pass << !
set heading off
set feedback off
select status from logging where id=4;
)
echo $X
if [ $X -eq 3 ]; 
 then
  (sqlplus -s user/pass << !
    set heading off
    set feedback off
        select * from products;
)
fi
```

Is this the option you were referring to. Now how do i run the SQL multiple times untill the condition is met.

Comment: Essentially, yes. You can wrap it in a loop and use the `sleep` command to wait 30 seconds before trying again.

Comment: Thanks a lot . I have finally fixed it today.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
start() {
v=`sqlplus -s <<!
HR/HR
set pages 0 echo off feed off
select distinct status from
emp
where
id=5;
!
`
echo $v;

}
while :
do
  rval=`start`
  if [ "$rval" -eq 4 ]
  then
    echo if condition true
    sqlplus -l scott/tiger <<EOF
    select * from department;
    EXIT
EOF
    break
  else
     sleep 30
  fi
done
```